# Location of policies.json for snap installation of brave browser?

Tags: snap, brave, policy

Where can one place the/a `policies.json` file such that the snap installation of the brave browser recognises it?

[this discussion](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/19052) suggests `/etc/brave/policies` or `/etc/brave/policies/managed`. That is also consistent with [this resolved issue](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/19052). However, neither of those seem to be recognised in the `brave://policy/` tab:

[image]

### Ubuntu Version

`lsb_release -a` returns:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.10
Release:    22.10
Codename:   kinetic
```

### Brave version

`snap list brave` returns:

```
Name   Version   Rev  Tracking       Publisher  Notes
brave  1.50.125  228  latest/stable  brave
```

### Demonstrating policies.json exists

The output of `ls /etc/brave/policies` is:

```
managed  policies.json
```

And the output of `cat /etc/brave/policies/policies.json` is:

```
{
  "policies": {
    "Certificates": {
      "Install": [
        "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.crt"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

For completeness:
`ls /usr/local/share/ca-certificates` returns:

```
ca.crt
```